# ckeditor blur and dialog

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, blur

I have a blur function attached to my ckeditor like so

```
editor = CKEDITOR.instances.fck;
editor.on("blur",function(e){
    alert("hello");
});
```

you with me  ?

now when I click on the flash button the editor blurs and causes the alert to show.

how to I stop that from happening and still get the alert to appear other times like when the user leave the editor area

thanks again

Answer (score 6):

As long as we're working on hacks, here's what I like to use to solve this problem.  The key is that CKE uses iFrames for their drop-down type controls (color picker and background color, font size, font type)

```
 editor.on("blur", function(e) {
  if ($(document.activeElement).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() != "iframe") {
      // your code here for "real" blur event
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The blur event is firing when you click on a button like flash after the up click when the dialog is presented. The blur event that you want on happens right after mouse down outside the editor. This is dirty but by tracking the mouse state you can achieve your goal.

```
$(function() {
    var mouseState = 0;
    $(document).mousedown(function(){ mouseState = 1; });
    $(document).mouseup(  function(){ mouseState = 0; });

    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
    editor.on("blur", function(e) {
        if (mouseState == 1) console.log("blur");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem now as well.

My solution was to wrap the editor inside a holder, let's call it id="holder", and bind this event:

```
var isMouseOverEditor = false;
$('#holder').hover(function(){
  isMouseOverEditor = (e.type=='mouseenter' ? true : false);
});
```

Later at the on blur event of the editor:

```
editor.on("blur", function(e) {
  if (!isMouseOverEditor) return;
  // your code here for "real" blur event
});
```

It's not the best solution, but it's a nice workaround that can be used. It seems that the blur event of the editor is binded to the editor itself. Meaning that when the editing area is blured, the event fired.

Hope this helps anyone has this problem.